# what is the use of "v=747" at the end of /site_media/base.css?v=747"

Tags: html, css

I have seen a web page source code containing the following css declaration at the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/base.css?v=747" />
```

What is the use of "**?v=747**" at the end of this CSS declaration?

Comment: CSS questions are better asked on http://doctype.com than on SO.

Comment: @EBGreen: it's not a css question.

Comment: I could have sworn that it was tagged CSS and it was specifically asking about the CSS declaration. My mistake.

Comment: @EBGreen: Not everything tagged css is about CSS itself. This question for example is about how a style sheet is referenced in HTML, not about the CSS in the style sheet.

Comment: Oh...so it's HTML. Sorry. In that case: HTML questions are better asked on http://doctype.com than on SO.

Comment: And before you ask, from doctype: "...questions about CSS, HTML, web design and email design."

Comment: IMHO, both CSS and HTML are within the purview of "web development", and thus programming related.  There are tons of such questions already on SO, and I don't think we should be turning them away.  Did I miss a memo or something?

Comment: What´s with the *CSS questions are better asked on doctype.com than on SO* remarks? I´ve been seeing that a lot recently. A new trend or someone promoting his own site? By the way, SO seems the perfect place for css, html, etc. questions...

Comment: doctype was added to what Jeff has dubbed the StackOverflow League of Justice (LoJ) specifically to handle HTML/CSS questions. That is why it is linked at the bottom of every page.

Comment: For what it is worth, the SO FAQ spells this out as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To bypass the caching mechanism of the browser. If the file is updated, the version (I guess that's what **v** stands for) will be incremented and the browser will not use the cache, but download the file, since it is a different URL.

Comment: In fact, the browser will never cache that file, because GET requests with parameters are not cached by conforming HTTP implementations.

Comment: **Conforming**, being the important word. Two letters: **IE**

Comment: It is possible to configure Opera to cache GET requests.  This is usually a bad idea, but there are some special situations where it can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

It prevents browser caching from being an issue with new releases of the webapp

Answer (score 3):

Typically the ? designates that following code is the query string for the url. Probably this site is running code to create a dynamic css file

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote? This was what I thought at first too. I'm not a web developer so the reason may be obvious to those more savvy than me.

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening in this case...but it's certainly *possible* that that's what's happening, and no one else has mentioned it, so +1.

Comment: I agree with jereon. I have had .jpeg files with parameters. ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably a version number.  When the value for `v` changes, the browser will think it is a new file and fetch it (so that the file is not cached by the browser between different versions).