# where to change Eclipse IDE settings to ignore question marks on css reference

Tags: html, css, eclipse

using eclipse, my html page is referencing css files, but is causing eclipse to mark it as an "error" with squiggly lines below the link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smoothness/jquery-ui.css?" />
```

if i remove the question mark, the error goes away. but i do not want to do that due to [what-does-the-question-mark-at-then-end-of-a-css-include-url-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634123/what-does-the-question-mark-at-then-end-of-a-css-include-url-do)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

so eclipse experts, where can i change this setting to get eclipse to ignore this issue?

Comment: What's the error's message?

Comment: it says "undefined css file" (even though it is working and picking the css file)

Comment: Maybe you've installed something that's pulled in https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources ? WTP itself doesn't validate Link element references.

Comment: i didnt... this is a pretty standard eclipse setup.

Comment: Which downloaded file did you start with? What have you installed since?

Comment: ok. it looks like i do have  Eclipse WTP HTML-Web resources v1.0.0.201508312110 installed in my eclipse. i beleive this is what came with eclipse mars. what does this mean? should i remove this install?